PrimeNG SplitButton Items Display Incorrect Styles in Angular Standalone Application
In my Angular standalone application, when I try to use PrimeNG components like SplitButton and Button, the styles don't appear as expected. Here's a screenshot of the issue I'm facing:
the two buttons
Here’s how I’m using the components:
<p-splitButton 

        label="Login"         
        severity="primary" 
        [model]="loginItems">            
        </p-splitButton>      


<p-button>click me</p-button>  


And here’s my configuration in angular.json:
"styles": [             
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],

